# Triggering a controller action after the view is completely loaded

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC 5 and I need to make a service call (WCF service) after the view has finished loading. I don't want to block the UI until that service call finishes.

My question is, is there a way for me to trigger the service call, after the current view has finished loading, without any user interactions (i.e without clicking on any link or button)?

I tried making the call from JavaScript (just before the end of the jQuery ready function, but of it was of no use) that the current view uses.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [How to: Call WCF Service Operations Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Call it inside the document ready function `$(document).ready(function() {$ajax.....});`

Comment: You might want to use `$(window).`[`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load)`(function () { $.ajax... })` instead, as that occurs after all scripts, stylesheets, and images (and a number of other things) are loaded.